# ts-node not picking up d.ts files, but tsc compiling works fine

Tags: typescript, express

I'm using typescript with express, trying to extend express' request object.

Here is my server.ts:

```
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
const app = express();
app.use(function(req: Request, res: Response, next) {
    req.testVal = 200;
});
```

Here is my extends.d.ts:

```
declare namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
        testVal: number;
    }
}
```

I'm developing using VSCode. The IDE doesn't give me any warning.

Compiling with `tsc` also works just fine.

However, when I run this with `ts-node`, I got error message:

```
src/server.ts:19:9 - error TS2339: Property 'testVal' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary>'.

19     req.testVal = 200;
           ~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen in one of my projects.  My solution was to pass the `--files` flag to ts-node:

```
ts-node --files server.ts
```

See [the docs](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#help-my-types-are-missing) where it says:

> If you must use files, include, or exclude, enable --files flags or set TS_NODE_FILES=true

Answer (score 0):

To declare `testVal`, you can use code below:

**Option 1:**

```js
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      testVal : number
    }
  }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```js
declare module 'express' {
  interface Request {
    testVal : number
  }
}
```

I hope It's work.

Comment: this pops up "Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations."

Comment: Because I have tried your `code` and it gives an error, but when I use` code` above, it's working fine.